# Placing words one below the other in Moderncv

Tags: line-spacing

I am trying to place words one below the other in the following sentence:

```
{\textbf{Computing} - Matlab } 
\hspace{88pt} 
{\textbf{Office tools} - MS-Office}
\hspace{90pt}
{\textbf{PLM} - Teamcenter}\\ 
{\textbf{Engineering} - DFMEA, DVPR, DFM,} 
\hspace{20pt}
{\textbf{Administrative} - BOM, ESOW, RFP} \\ 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3mm} 
{DFA, FTA, GD$\&$T}
```

I want the last line to start at the same point where the second last line starts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP answered it himself in a comment

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is as following:

Not beautiful, but working:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\newlength{\hintscolumnwidth}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{-80pt}  %to fit your stuff in one line
\parbox{0.9\paperwidth}{ %to fit your stuff in one line
\parbox{0.33\linewidth}{
{\textbf{Computing} - Matlab } \\
{\textbf{Engineering} - DFMEA, DVPR, DFM,} 
}
\parbox{0.33\linewidth}{
{\textbf{Office tools} - MS-Office}\\
{\textbf{Administrative} - BOM, ESOW, RFP}
}
\parbox{0.33\linewidth}{
{\textbf{PLM} - Teamcenter}\\ 
\mbox{}\\ %to match the automatic line breaks in the other boxes. I tried other versions, but they didnt work
\mbox{} %same here
}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3mm} 
{DFA, FTA, GD$\&$T}
}%to fit your stuff in one line

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps stacks could help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\Longunderstack{%
  \textbf{Computing} - Matlab\cr
  \textbf{Engineering} - \stackunder{DFMEA, DVPR, DFM,}{DFA, FTA, GD$\&$T}%
}\hfill
\Longunderstack{%
  \textbf{Office tools} - MS-Office\cr
  \textbf{Administrative} - BOM, ESOW, RFP%
}\hfill
\textbf{PLM} - Teamcenter
\end{document}
```

[image]